# FD Table is full error while sending email using SES

Tags: php, email, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send 2K emails to my customers. I'm using Amazon SES to send the email using [this](https://github.com/daniel-zahariev/php-aws-ses) library. When I try to send the email with the attachment, I'm getting `SimpleEmailService::sendEmail(): 35 Process open FD table is full` error. I just followed the instruction given in the readme file. And changed credentials only. Any help will be appreciated... :)

**Edit**

Almost 900 emails with the attachment sent successfully. But after that, it starts throwing the error.

The attachment is of type PDF.

**Edit 2**

> The service team says that you are not closing the file descriptor after sending the mails. You need to close the file descriptor after the job is done. That way it wont exhaust the limit set on the number of FDs assigned

Here is the code I'm trying.

```
$mails = [
'customer@email.com'
...
...
...
];

$ses = new SimpleEmailService('XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX');
$ses->enableVerifyPeer(false);
$m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();

foreach ($mails as $email) {
    try {
        $m->setFrom('From <example@email.com>');
        $m->setSubject('Subject');
        $m->setMessageFromString('','<p>This is the test email.</p>');
        $m->addTo($email);
        $atch = path to pdf;
        $mime_type = @mime_content_type($atch);
        $tmp = str_replace('\\','/', $atch);
        $file_name = basename($tmp);
        $m->addAttachmentFromFile($file_name, $atch, $mime_type);
        $response = $ses->sendEmail($m,false,true);
        $m->clearRecipients();
        $m->attachments = [];
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The service team says that you are not closing the file descriptor after sending the mails."*  Maybe.  Are you sending the same PDF file to each recipient, or are you generating them individually and mailing them, in a loop?  Show some code?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

Just added `$ses->setBulkMode(true);` after `$ses->enableVerifyPeer(false);`. ..:)